# jQuery How do I focus on contents of iframe after clearing

Tags: jquery

I currently have a wysiwyg iframe where the user can submit input to another area on the page. Once the iframe input is submitted, I set it to clear the content. I want to also automatically focus back into the iframe.

This is the code I currently have:

```
postContentClr = $("iframe#textarea1IFrame").contents().find("body")
postContentClr.html(" ").focus();
```

Comment: Ok we know what you want to do. And what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: The iframe doesn't get focus. In other words, as soon as the user clicks 'submit' and the previous (not-mentioned here) action is completed, I want the focus to go back to the "textbox" so they can continue typing a new message right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to simply focus on the parent. And Jitter is correct, since I already declared it as a jQuery object, it needn't be wrapped.

Working code:

```
postContentClr = $("iframe#textarea1IFrame").contents().find("body")
postContentClr.html("").parent().focus();
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but `postContentClr` is a jQuery object, so calling `html()` requires that you access it via jQuery like so:

```
$(postContentClr).html('').focus();
```

Comment: wrong. as you state yourself it is already a jQuery object. So no need to rewrap it